# Ejabberd - get user from multi user chat message using Smack XMPP client or enforce nickname

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack, multiuserchat

I am running an ejabberd server with a series of locked down multi user chats (members only, registration required, no subject change or PMs permitted etc)
One requirement is to strictly identify which users (from their user Id/account Jid when registering with the server) are present in each room, and which user has sent a message.

How this is achieved is not important, it can either be:
a) By getting the userId from message.getFrom()
b) By getting the nick/resource part from the message sender, and enforcing what nick a user can choose

In direct messages, the Jid of a sender will look like:

> <userId>@<domain>/<resourcepart>

so I can take the userId (LocalPart) and not worry too much what nickname was chosen.

This is not possible in multi user chats however, since the Jid will appear as:

> <roomName>@conference.<domain>/<resourcepart>

The userId of the sender is not present, so I have to rely on the nickname, but this can be set to anything by the users (and changed at any point in the chat)

Is there a way to enforce how a nick is set? (i.e. set to the same value as userId) or otherwise extract the userId from a multi user chat message?

Comment: It seems that you use pseudo-anonymous rooms, when you actually want to use non-anonymous rooms. This, per room, setting can be configured.

Comment: We already have `default_room_options: anonymous: false` set in ejabberd.yml, but smack client can still only view the JID as `<roomname>@conference.<domain>/<resourcepart>`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote, you need a non-anonymous room. The real XMPP address (JID) of a room occupant will then be part of the participant's presence ([XEP-0045 § 7.2.3](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-nonanon)). You can obtain the presence of a occupant via [`MultiUserChat.getOccupantPresence​(EntityFullJid user)`](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.4.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#getOccupantPresence(org.jxmpp.jid.EntityFullJid)). From this `Presence` you want to extra the `MUCUser` information via [`MUCUser.from(presence)`](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.4.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/packet/MUCUser.html#from(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Stanza)). From which you extra the `MUCIitem` which should allow to retrieve the real JID via `MUCItem.getJid()`<sup>1</sup>.

1: Note that the javadoc if this method seems to be misleading, it should contain the real JID of the user and not the MUC JID.

Comment: I get "The method getOccupantPresence​(EntityFullJid) is undefined for the type MultiUserChat" if I try to call this method. Using Smack v4.4.6

Comment: Ok, above error was caused by a glitch in Eclipse. It's now working well and is the solution I was looking for

Comment: Actually, this approach only seems to work if the user is still present in the room. If the user sends a message then leaves, clients which then connect to retrieve historic messages are unable to lookup the real JID this way as the presence is no longer available

Answer (score 1):

There is a room option that allows all room occupants to view the real Jabber ID of other occupants. By default only room moderators can view those real Jabber ID.

An alternative would be to customize the source code to only accept a room join if the nick is identical to the username in the JID, and don't accept any nick change afterwards.

Comment: The first option is preferable, but I though that's what `default_room_options: anonymous: false` was supposed to achieve? Interestingly, the admin account that is connecting (also using smack client) has the same issue - only able to view JID as `<roomname>@conference.<domain>/<resourcepart>`

Answer (score 1):

The answer given above by [Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194894/flow) works well for users who are still present in the room. However, for historic messages where the user has left the room, the Presence will not be available.

For users without a Presence, the message stanza will contain an address node, e.g.:

```
<message 
    xmlns='jabber:client' 
    xml:lang='en' 
    to='bob@example.com/12345'
    from='dummyroom@conference.example.com/johnny' 
    id='purple44d872cb' type='groupchat'>
    <addresses xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'>
        <address xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address' type='ofrom' jid='john@example.com/12345'/>
    </addresses>
    <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2023-01-27T10:08:59.594+00:00' from='dummyroom@conference.example.com'/>
    <body>me</body>
</message>
```

To extract this in smack I've called the message `toXML()` method to get the stanza (required upgrade to smack v4.4.x), then used an XML parser to extract the `jid` attribute, i.e.:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jxmpp.jid.EntityFullJid;
import org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate;

public static EntityFullJid getUserJIDFromMessage(MultiUserChat muc, Message message) {
    EntityFullJid jid = null;
    
    //1. Extract JID from presence
    try {
        EntityFullJid channelJid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom(message.getFrom());
        jid = extractJidFromPresence(muc, channelJid);
        if (jid != null) return jid;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    
    //2. If presence unavailable, parse the stanza
    Document messageDoc = Jsoup.parse(message.toXML().toString());
    for (Element address: messageDoc.select("addresses").select("address")) {
        if (address.attr("type").equals("ofrom")) {
            try {
                jid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom(address.attr("jid"));
                return jid;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    } return null;
}

private static EntityFullJid extractJidFromPresence(MultiUserChat muc, EntityFullJid channelJid) {
    EntityFullJid jid = null;
    try {
        MUCUser mucUser = MUCUser.from(muc.getOccupantPresence(channelJid));
        jid = (EntityFullJid) mucUser.getItem().getJid();
        return jid;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return jid;
}
```